# Pixel Location of Sentinel 1 & Sentinel 2 and SRTM

Tags: sentinel-2, resolution, sentinel-1

I am processing integration S1, S2 and SRTM, since their pixel grid does not align with each other I am figuring out how to snap with them all into one grid. Before coming with specific reprojection or resampling techniques I want to know which corner of the pixel is representing ground coordinates for each satellite image (S1,S2, SRTM). I have checked the user guide and technical guide but didn't get the idea yet at the pixel level.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but for sentinel 2 it's should be the upper left corner of the pixel. Check this [link](https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/product-types/level-1c).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. For S2 it in the upper-left corner of the pixel coordinates which will be also ground coordinates, it might have some geometric error up to 3m for 10m bands, 6m for 20m bands.